# Heapsort - Why the loop in PercolateDown() iterates (length/2) times?

Tags: c++, heapsort

[Here we see a function PercolateDown() implemented in C++.](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page505.html)

I just could not understand Why the loop ends at, length/2 times ?

[Moreover, Why the loop in build heap starts at n/2?](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page506.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you build the max/min-heap, you don't need to heapify(PercolateDown) the leafs, as they can't have any children which are bigger/smaller then their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the C++ source code in the textbook uses 1-based indexes, 
i.e. `array[0]` is not used and `array[n]` should be a valid reference into the array data.

That is **not** consistent with C++ standard conventions (arrays, vector etc. with zero-based indexes 0 ... n-1).

To illustrate the (1-based) index numbers (not the values) inside a heap:

```
         1
     2       3
  4    5   6   7
8  9 10
```

If you read the text given by your links carefully, you will see that each parent node at position `i` in a heap has children at positions `2*i`and `2*i+1` only if these positions do not exceed the length of the array.

Since the PercolateDown() algorithm swaps parents with their children, only `length/2` iterations are needed.

Moreover, the heap is constructed from bottom to top. Therefore, the iteration starts at `n/2` going up, i.e. towards position `1`.